# How to modify retrieve from dataset/database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am a beginner to this so I am trying an example to understand so I really appreciate your help.

I have the following web application structure:

[image]

I have the following code for clicking the button "save" which saves the text written in the 3 text boxes into the 3 fields of the table `Trial` in database:

```
protected void AddProgramButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DataBinder ds = new DataBinder();
    sqlcon.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Trial VALUES (@FirstColumn, @SecondColumn , @ThirdColumn)", sqlcon);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstColumn", RadTextBox1.Text);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondColumn", RadTextBox2.Text);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ThirdColumn", RadTextBox3.Text);

    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //   lbl.Visible = true;
    sqlcon.Close();
}
```

My question is ::

The column `FirstColumn` in the table `Trial` is primary key field. So, I don't want to save the data into the database directly , BUT I want it to first check the value I entered in `RadTextBox1` and see if it exists in the database or not ::

- If it exists, then it will display the corresponding values in `RadTextBox2` and  `RadTextBox3`
- If it doesn't exist , then `RadTextBox2` and  `RadTextBox3` will remain blank and allow user to enter new data.

How can I do that ? I have been searching a lot but it is so confusing as I just started learning this. I reallyy appreciate your help.

Comment: `AddProgramButton_Click` event inserts the data from textboxes. For binding Textboxes with table fields you have to select data from database.

Comment: How do I select the data from the database here?

Comment: Another method which performs `Select` operation on database and return you a value required to be bind with TextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datareader for this,

```
if(RadTextBox2.Text!=""||RadTextBox3.Text!="")
{
RadTextBox2.Text="";
RadTextBox3.Text="";
}
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your connection");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Trial where FirstColumn = '"+RadTextBox1.Text+"'",con);
SQlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
  if(dr.HasRows())
  {

     RadTextBox2.Text = dr.GetString(1);
     RadTextBox3.Text = dr.GetString(2);  
  }
  else
  {


  }
}
con.Close();
```

It will come on your RadTextBox1 change event.Make sure your RadTextBox1 autopostback property set to true.

Comment: But there is something ,, if I enter a number in the first textbox that doesn't exist in the beginning, it will leave the other text boxed empty; however if I try an existing number and it will display the corresponding values in the other 2 boxes THEN enter a number that doesn't exist, radtextbox2 and radtextbox3 still have the previous values of the previous execution.. i can't clear them ?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean. Can you explain with some example ?, or some more brief ?

Comment: Yes you can. Now i got your point. Check with my answer again. I have changed in else part. Try it, and let me know.

Comment: Check it now. I have changed in else part.

Comment: Try it now. I have made some changes.

Comment: Have you set textbox auto post back property to true ?

Comment: Check it now. I have been moved the few line of codes into upper part.

Comment: It works !! Thanks a lot , I really appreciate your help and cooperation :)